# How to count data from a row and put in a table in Excel?

Tags: excel, count

I have a sheet where I put in the data of the classes and periods which students sign up for. It looks like below:

[image: Data table]

There are 3 courts in total. Classes from each court goes from Monday till Sunday and there are three periods, morning, noon and evening.

I want to be able to count how many students are there in a particular class because each of our classes have a limit of 30 students. So I need Excel to count this for me put the count number in the following kind of table:

[image: Count table]

I've tried COUNTIF many times but I'm always unable to figure out the correct criteria for Excel to count.

Comment: please post the `COUNTIF` formula that you tried

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking to count instances where the period, day,and the court match.

The function I used was COUNTIFS(), to account for multiple criteria.

```
COUNTIFS(DayRange,Day,PeriodRange,Period,CourtRange,Court)
  My actual formula was this: 
COUNTIFS(C$15:C$20,$A5,D$15:D$20,C$2,B$15:C$20,"Ams")
```

Note, that DayRange, PeriodRange and CourtRange have to the the exact same dimensions (i.e. 1 column x 6 rows).